# Há algum modo de iniciar uma Thread que está em um método em outra classe?

Tags: java, thread

Tenho um método e dentro dele uma thread, eu precisava "startar" ele de outra classe e depois verificar quando a Thread acabou. É possível fazer isso? meu código:

```
Thread th;

public void inserir(){
    th = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            //aqui ficam minhas inserções
        }
    };
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma correta de resolver isso é extrair a classe anônima que implementa a *thread* de forma que você possa fazer reuso.

Exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasse {

    //inner class
    private Runnable insercao = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //aqui ficam minhas inserções
        }
    };

    //executa e continua
    public void inserirAssincrono() {
        new Thread(insercao).start();
    }

    //executa e espera
    public void inserirSincrono() {
        Thread t = new Thread(insercao);
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join(); //espera a thread terminar antes de continuar
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

No entanto, existem várias possibilidades de como isso pode ser implementado dependendo da necessidade.